# Flutter Deep Linking with Multiple Navigators

Tags: android, flutter

I am writing a Flutter app where I have a bottom nav bar. Each tab of the bottom nav bar has its own Navigator maintaining its own navigation stack. The main screen holds a stack of `Offstage` `Navigators` whose visibility is switched between by tapping the bottom nav tabs.

I am using the `Navigator 1.0` approach to handle all my navigation.

I would like to enable deep linking in such a way that, depending on the deep link route, I can choose the appropriate bottom nav tab to select and push the `MaterialPageRoute` onto the `Navigator` responsible for that tab.

I already have the logic responsible for switching between tabs from any place within the app. I also use `onGenerateRoute()` to determine which route should be pushed upon receiving a deep link intent.

I would like to know if it is in any way possible to instruct a navigator other than the root navigator to push the desired route. Can this be done with using the possible parameters in `MaterialApp` such as `onGenerateRoute` or `onUnknownRoute`? Is this feasible without refactoring and migrating to `Navigator 2.0`?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Same problem here!

Answer (score 0):

Generate keys for each navigator, I'm assuming there are five.

```dart
    final _navigatorsKeys =
      List.generate(5, (index) => GlobalObjectKey<NavigatorState>('$index'));
```

Assign them to the respective navigators

```dart
    Navigator(
      key: _navigatorKeys[0],
        initialRoute: homeViewRoute,
        onGenerateRoute: generateRoute
    ),
    Navigator(
          key: _navigatorKeys[1],
            initialRoute: homeViewRoute,
            onGenerateRoute: generateRoute
        )...
```

You can them check the deep link to define to which tab it should navigate to, I suggest you prefix the links based on each navigation item. E.g.: `home/post, me/profile`. By doing this, you can change the tab index before navigating to the actual page.

Finally, to navigate to a page using the first navigator, you can do like this:

```dart
_navigatorsKeys[0].currentState!.pushNamed('home/posts');
```

Hope it helps.